# Get distance of sprite and Screen

Tags: java, libgdx, game-physics

How to get the distance between the edge of the screen and a vector moving sprite? I want to get the distance between  my moving sprite and the edge of the screen so that when my sprite touches the edge it will bounce of.

Comment: I recommend you use box2d for physical simulating instead of trying yourself. It's easy to learn.

Comment: Actually noone will answer this if you just ask for that. We need to know if you are using a camera whats your setup at the moment and so on. Depending on that the position can be different so give us a bit more details please.

Answer (score 0):

basically if you use a ortho2D projection like this :

```
Matrix4().setToOrtho2D(0, 0, (float) Gdx.graphics.getWidth(), (float) Gdx.graphics.getHeight());
```

**Gdx.graphics.getWidth()** will return the screen's right edge

**0** is the left edge.

To get distance you just have to subtract with your object's positions.

Answer (score 0):

To get the edges of the screen assuming these escenarios.

- **You aren't using a camera**.

  - X left edge = `0`
  - X right edge = `Gdx.graphics.getWidth()`
  - Y bottom edge = `0`
  - Y top edge = `Gdx.graphics.getHeight()`
- **You are using a camera (origin is at bottom-left of it)**.

  - X left edge = `0`
  - X right edge = `camera.viewportWidth()`
  - Y bottom edge = `0`
  - Y top edge = `camera.viewportHeight()`
- **You are using a camera (origin is not at bottom-left of it -moving camera-)**.

  - X left edge = `camera.position.x-camera.viewportWidth()/2`
  - X right edge = `camera.position.x+camera.viewportWidth()/2`
  - Y bottom edge = `camera.position.y-camera.viewportHeight()/2`
  - Y top edge = `camera.position.x+camera.viewportHeight()/2`

Get the spritePosition like this:

```
sprite.getX();
sprite.getY();
```

And check if is touching one of the edges, change its velocity to the other way.